# Using pyserial without installation?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyserial, qgis

I am working on a `PYQT-QGIS Application`, I want my application to require least number of external dependencies.(ideally none)

`Pyserial` is on of main library that I am using, so I was thinking to use this library without installation and let it be a part of my package.I remember using an old `pyserial` library for `QGIS Plugin`.

**Question:**
Is it still possible to use `pyserial lib` without installation? some pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current pyserial package setup.py, there seems to be some additional setup which is run when installing the egg:

```
setup(
    name = "pyserial" + suffix,
    description = "Python Serial Port Extension",
    version = version,
    author = "Chris Liechti",
    author_email = "cliechti@gmx.net",
    url = "http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/",
    packages = ['serial', 'serial.tools', 'serial.urlhandler'],
    license = "Python",
    long_description = "Python Serial Port Extension for Win32, Linux, BSD, Jython, IronPython",
    classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Python Software Foundation License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Operating System :: POSIX',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        #~ 'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows CE', # could work due to new ctypes impl. someone needs to confirm that
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.1',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2',
        'Topic :: Communications',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
        'Topic :: Terminals :: Serial',
    ],
    platforms = 'any',
    cmdclass = {'build_py': build_py, 'build_scripts': build_scripts},

    scripts = ['serial/tools/miniterm.py'],
)
```

Of note is the cmdclass and scripts sections. The egg is building the .py, .pyc and script files and appears to take into account the machine itself while doing so. Unless you prebuild the egg and deploy on the same platform/python etc. it may not work to just drop it in.

I highly recommend looking into Buildout for deploying your applications. It  handles dependencies/deployment issues for you in a reproducible and productive way. I currently use it to deploy arduino projects with Pyserial/PYQT/Pyside and it works very well. I will hopefully be able to share my GIT with an Arduino recipe on a future tutorial of this kind of thing.

Buildout can either grab the packages from the internet, or you can pre-load the eggs you want into your installer. It essentially allows your project to have a dedicated virtual environment with all eggs/scripts "installed" and configured just for it. This is especially useful for more complex packages like iPython Notebook, Django, or in your case PyQT/pyserial, since it actually installs/builds the eggs as if installing on the machine directly, but does so in a way that will not affect other tools/projects.

http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/